# Store date picker date and save in database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, date

Im trying to get the date from a date picker i have on my page and then have that date posted to a php function which will store the selected date in my database.

Comment: Show the code for the form your datepicker is in. I'd guess this is an issue with your form (and the values that `$_POST` from it) and not with your datepicker

Comment: @oflannabhra I have added the form i have the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstanding of how Javascript, HTML forms, and PHP work together.

Javascript (and jQuery) run in the browser. PHP runs on your server.

The browser initiates a request to your server, your server hands off the request to a php process which parses and runs your php. This generates html which is sent back to your browser. The javascript linked to or contained in `<script>` tags is then loaded, and run if necessary (or triggered by events). This is an oversimplification, but should get across the basics.

So, what is happening is the jQuery is running inside your browser to perform changes to the HTML. Specifically, it is inserting a string formatted as 'MM-DD-YYY' into your form field. When the user then posts this form, those values get added to the HTTP request that is sent to your server. Those values are then accessible in the `$_POST` variable in your php script, as a `key=>value` pair, where `key` is the HTML `name='formfield1'` attribute of your form. So your would access that as `$date = $_POST['formfield1']`.

Javascript, and jQuery specifically are doing nothing but loading a string value into that html field for the user. You can't access Javascript variables from your PHP.

If you post your form code, a more specific answer might be able to be given.

Edit: for an inline datepicker, you will need to configure your datepicker as follows:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    inline : true,
    altField : '#hiddenFieldID',
});
```

where `#hiddenFieldID` is a hidden input field in your form. Regardless, you have to attach the date value to your form in some way for it to be available in `$_POST`.

Comment: Am i unable to post data from a div? as my date picker is inline

Comment: Yes, you will need to change that line to
`<input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker"></div>`

Comment: Hmmm, so there is no way at all to do it? As the project I'm working on requires an inline calendar

Comment: The way i have done it is inline, i have checked the jQuery UI documentation and it was attached to a div.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you how to attach the value from the datepicker to an input field in your form.

Comment: You should accept answers you've gone on to use. You have 10 questions all with correct answers, none of which you've accepted. Please go back and accept correct answers on them.